# How can I hide slider buttons behind a sub menu?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

In wordpress I use the Skitter Slideshow plugin but when I open the top menu: and sub menu display on slider then the next button does not hide behind the sub menu. 
For more help I included a picture and you can see image links at the end of this question:
image 1 is default and without menu displaying but in 2 image you can see slider next button on the sub menu
buttun css code is :

```
background: url("../images/blog-felesh-r1.png") no-repeat scroll left top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
height: 53px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
right: 35px;
text-indent: -9999em;
top: 317px;
width: 53px;
z-index: 10000;
```

images for more help:
before menu displaying:
http://up.tractorfc.com/images/50135186097250441245.png

after menu open:
http://up.tractorfc.com/images/85386592157969197947.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the parent of the top menu should have a higher z-index than the main slider container.**

like:

```
#nav{z-index:3}
#slider{z-index:2}
```

They would each also need a `position` of `relative` `absolute` or `fixed`, for the z-index to take effect.

This will also work even if you keep a `z-index` of `10000` on the buttons, i added that in the fiddle to show that it is not the issue.

You shouldn't need to have a `z-index` as high as `10000` unless you never want something on top of it, but in this case that doesn't even matter.

Made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/a497M/

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked what z-index value have the submenu element and the buttons? Buttons must have lower z-index than the submenu if you want them to be hidden when submenu is shown.

Comment: Thanks
how much you suggest to decrease z-index value from 10000 ?

Comment: That's not how z-index works, it *can* work that way, but not in this instance.

Comment: @FileVer, why not? I agree with your answer that is not only z-index and you also need fixing a layout (with position, relative..), but why is not valid what I wrote in this instance?

Comment: because the elements in question have their own positioned parents, which makes the z-index of the buttons and subnav relative to their parents, not each other. So no matter what you change them to, it's not going to fix the issue. The positioned parents need to have different z-indices in order for them to stack properly. If it were a question between two siblings with the same parent, you would be correct.

Comment: @FileVer10, thank you for your explanation, I didn't know there was parents over them, :)

Comment: @Chococroc anytime you're dealing with z-index, you want to make all parent elements do the work for you. it's much easier to give them a z-index, and control the syntax order based on what should be on bottom first. That way you don't need a lot of elements with z-index. Anytime there's a slideshow and navigation competing, you need to do it that way because the slideshow alters z-index on each slide, and most of the time it does it differently in each broswer, so the index isn't dependable, which is fixed by giving the parent a position and z-index.